# Selector interpreted as HTML on my website. Can an attacker easily exploit this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, security

I have a website that is only accessible via https.

It does not load any content from other sources. So all content is on the local webserver.

Using the Retire.js Chrome plugin I get a warning that the jquery 1.8.3 I included is vulnerable to 'Selector interpreted as HTML'
(jQuery bug [11290](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11290))

I am trying to motivate for a quick upgrade, but I need something more concrete information to motivate the upgrade to the powers that be. 
My question are :

- Given the above, should I be worried ?
- Can this result in a XSS type attack ?

Comment: Why not use any version of jQuery released in the last three years, since the bug was fixed?! E.g., [v1.9](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/) or later (ideally, you know, v1.11.3 or v2.1.4 as I write this).

Comment: Good point @T.J. Crowder , unfortunately I am taking the website over from someone else and it is a large website that the testers will need to retest manually :(

Comment: Look at the API changes since v1.8.3, you won't find much to worry you. Using old stuff is always leaving the door open.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder. If it was up to me, I would upgrade now. Unfortunately they require weeks of testing with the normal dev cycle. I want to know how to motivate the upgrade sooner to the power that be, saying that an attacker can exploit this easily.
Right now all I have is the jQuery bug which is not much to go on.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder PS stackoverflow.com uses jQuery 1.7.1 and it's vulnerable to the same issue.

Comment: And? So Stack Overflow's doing something silly, using a 3.5-year-out-of-date version, missing out on all those lovely bugfixes in the meantime. What does that have to do with anything? It doesn't, for instance, make it a *good idea*. I'm still slightly involved with a website using Java applets and PrototypeJS. Also not a good idea. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the author of Retire.js let me shed some light on this. There are two weaknesses in older versions of jQuery, but those are not vulnerabilities by themselves. It depends on how jQuery is used. Two examples abusing the bugs are shown here: research.insecurelabs.org/jquery/test/

The two examples are:

```
$("#<img src=x onerror=...>")
```

and

```
$("element[attribute='<img src=x onerror=...>'")
```

Typically this becomes a problem if you do something like:

```
$(location.hash)
```

This was a fairly common pattern for many web sites, when single page web sites started to occur.

So this becomes a problem if and only if you put untrusted user data inside the jQuery selector function.

And yes the end result is XSS, if the site is in fact vulnerable. https will not protect you against these kinds of flaws.

Comment: Thanks @Erlend . So even if I website uses these features, the content inside needs to be dynamic to have this weaknesses ?

Comment: Yes, but it's important to remember what can be dynamic. It can be server side data, but it can also be client side browser properties like location, window.name etc.

Answer (score 5):

What the bug is telling you is that jQuery may mis-identify a selector containing a `<` as being an HTML fragment instead, and try to parse and create the relevant elements.

So the vulnerability, such as it is, is that a cleverly-crafted selector, if then passed into jQuery, could define a `script` tag that then executes arbitrary script code in the context of the page, potentially taking private information from the page and sending it to someone with malicious (or merely prurient) intent.

This is largely only useful if User A can write a selector that will later be given to jQuery in User B's session, letting User A steal information from User B's page. (It really doesn't matter if a user can "tricky" jQuery this way on their **own** page; they can do far worse things from the console, or with "save as".)

So: If nothing in your code lets users provide selectors that will be saved and then retrieved by other users and passed to jQuery, I wouldn't be all that worried. If it does (with or without the fix to the bug), I'd examine those selector strings **really carefully**. I say "with or without the bug" because if you didn't filter what the users typed at all, they could still just provide an HTML fragment where the first non-whitespace character is `<`, which would still cause jQuery to parse it as an HTML fragment.

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder . So potentially a session can be hijacked by this kind of vulnerability ?

Comment: @rjdkolb: Does your code store user-supplied selectors and then use them in another user's session?

Comment: Thanks again. As far as I can tell no, but there are a lot of pages to go though. On my first search, all selectors are only in the local browser context.